# Using Class::DBI and table names with hyphens

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, dbi

I have some old tables I wanted to work on using `Class::DBI` however when I tried setting it up with a table with a hyphen in the name I got a SQL error back when I try to use my class.

My class definition:

```
MyClass->table('table-name');
```

Shortened error message:
`DBD::mysql::st execute failed [..] near '-name [..]`

(My setup works fine with tables with no hyphen in the name.)

Is there a way to tell `Class::DBI` the table names that have hyphens?

I also notice the rest of the SQL that's spat out does not have fields enclosed in backticks ``` `` ``` possibly meaning any column names with hyphens would also fail.

Comment: `Class::DBI` doesn't appear to have been updated since 2007. Everyone I know has migrated to [`DBIx::Class`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class).

Comment: Yea I was already looking at that really..

Comment: How'd you get hyphens in your table names?

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe try: MyClass->table('"TABLE-NAME"'); -- you may have to get the case exact (i.e. matches what's in your database) though when you use quotes.

Comment: Not really, but going on that suggestion '\`table-name\`' did. Would still rather use DBIx, yet to see if that has the same quirk.

Comment: Indeed it does. Same fix applies.

Answer (score 1):

Giving MySQL its backticks did the trick:

```
MyClass->table('`table-name`')
```

As an aside, column names with hyphens can be defined the following way in order not to break Perl:

```
__PACKAGE__->add_columns('`col-name`' => {accessor => 'col_name'}); # or w/e valid Perl sub name like instead of col_name
```